# Reading csv file to dictionary - only reads first key+value

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a function that reads a csv file into a dictionary but the next iterator seems to not be working since it inly reads the first pair key+value.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(folder_path+'/information.csv'))
info = next(reader)
```

My csv file is structured this way:

```
Test Name
mono1
Date
18/03/2021
Time
18:25
Camera
monochromatic
```

and the dictionary return is:

```
{'Test Name': 'mono1'}
```

Any idea of what's happening? Or a better way to read the file without having to change its structure?

Comment: "but the next iterator seems to not be working since it inly reads the first pair key+value." I'm not sure what you expect `next` to do, but it gives you the *next value in the iterator*. In this case, the first value. Probably you meant `list(reader)`

Comment: Read the documentation for `csv.DictReader`. The column headers are used as keys. The row values are used as values for the dictionary. So if you did `next(reader)` a couple more times you'd get `{'Test Name': 'Date'}` and `{'Test Name': '18/03/2021'}`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I now understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not a CSV.  It would need to be structured as follows:

```
Test Name,Date,Time,Camera
mono1,18/03/2021,18:25,monochromatic
```

Which would be read with:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
{'Test Name': 'mono1', 'Date': '18/03/2021', 'Time': '18:25', 'Camera': 'monochromatic'}
```

To read the file you have, you could use:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = iter(f)  # An iterator over the lines of the file
    info = {}
    for line in lines:  # gets a line (key)
        # rstrip() removes the newline at the end of each line
        info[line.rstrip()] = next(lines).rstrip() # next() fetches another line (value)
print(info)
```

(same output)